# Trying to append something to a list in a list, instead appends to all lists in list

Tags: python, list

**Background**

Consider the following code:

```
list_of_lists = [[]] * 5
list_of_lists[2].append(123)
print(list_of_lists)
```

I would expect the result to be

```
[[], [], [123], [], []]
```

But instead the result is

```
[[123], [123], [123], [123], [123]]
```

Clearly, the `[[]] * 5` creates a list of 5 of the same object, so any reference to one of them, is a reference to all of them.

**Question**

How do I circumvent this? Can I append something to *one* of the lists in a list?

Comment: Use: `list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: _How do I circumvent this?_ Multiplying the inner list causes the identical references.  So, use some method other than multiplication.  For example `list_of_lists = [[], [], [], [], []]`

Answer (score 1):

Your current `list_of_lists` is a list of five references to a single list, so there is no such thing as "one of them" that you could append to without affecting the "others" (there are no others -- it's just one list with five names).  To create a list of five references to five lists, do:

```
list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Each time the expression `[]` is evaluated, a list is created.  The difference is that in `[[]] * 5` the inner `[]` is only being evaluated once (and then the outer list is being multiplied, which does not entail  any sort of copying of the values within the list), whereas in `[[] for _ in range(5)]` the inner `[]` is being evaluated once per iteration of `for _ in range(5)`.